# Add square bracket to the first character of string

Tags: ruby, string

I need to put the first character within square brackets. For example, I want to convert `"abc"` to `"[a]bc"`. How do I do this in ruby using regex?

Comment: I don't think using regex is a solution here, you're not trying to match anything.

Comment: Is There any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regex:

```
"abc".sub(/(.)/, '[\1]')
```

Without regex:

```
s = "abc"
s[0] = "[#{s[0]}]"
```

Comment: The return value of the second one is not the replaced string. You need to call `s` to see the replaced string.

Comment: Yes I did that. Still I'll check oncemore.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8? If so, then replace `s[0]` with `s[0, 1]`.

Comment: Yes. Right now I am running on ruby 1.8.7

Comment: which one you would prefer, If I call this conversion in every second?.

Comment: I would prefer the second one. I believe it requires less computation than using regex.

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading Ruby. 1.8.7 is five years old and 1.8 is ten years. "We will no longer support 1.8.7 in all senses after June 2013". http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/ 

The following works on 1.9+ versions of Ruby.

If it's only once a second then I can't think of a solution that wouldn't work. A naive `s = "[" + s[0] + "]" + s[1..-1]` would do. Changing the `+` to `<<` probably even makes it perform well.

Comment: Interpolation is faster than `+` or `<<`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
s = "abc"
p "abc".insert(1, ']').prepend('[') #=> "[a]bc"
```