# How to add [ ] brackets around first character of a word using bash

Tags: bash, sed

My question is described here [Add square bracket to the first character of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187824/add-square-bracket-to-the-first-character-of-string) .

Using the above link reference, I am trying from past 4 hours to get the result using bash.

Any workaround using sed.

```
#!/bin/bash
DESC="openerp-server"

initial="$(echo "$DESC" | sed 's/(.)/'[\1]'/g')"
echo $initial
```

Thanks.

Comment: You current attempt is almost correct. You just need to drop the single quotes around: `'[\1]'` and escape the `()` in the matching group: `\(.\)`. Alternatively you can pass the option `-r` to `sed`. Using it, it will not being longer required to escape the `()`. (But `-r` is not POSIX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
echo "string" | sed 's/^\(.\)/[\1]/'
echo "string" | sed 's/./[\0]/'         # The same but simplified
```

Output:

```
[s]tring
```

Comment: Great! I am kicking myself. Could you suggest me a starting place to learn sed. I appreciate the answer.. :-)

Comment: I would suggest this [O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do)

Answer (score 2):

`bash` provides an extension to the standard parameter expansion operators that lets you easily access the first character and the remaining characters of a parameter.

```
$ DESC="openerp-server"
$ DESC="[${DESC:0:1}]${DESC:1}"
$ echo "$DESC"
[o]penerp-server
```

A POSIX-compatible version is slightly longer, requiring a temporary variable to hold the tail.

```
$ DESC="openerp-server"
$ DESC_tail=${DESC#?}
$ DESC="[${DESC%$DESC_tail}]$DESC_tail"
$ echo "$DESC"
[o]penerp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
echo "string" | awk '{$1="["$1"]"}8' FS= OFS=
[s]tring
```